# Java - how to insert data into data base from txt file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am wondering how to read in a file and insert into a table in my data base. I written this:

```
String customerFile = "customer.txt";
Connection myConnect = ....
Statement mySt = myConnect.createStatement();
mySt.executeUpdate(..create customer table..);

        int SSN;
        String CNAME;
        String GENDER;
        int AGE;
        String PROFESSION;
        String line;
        String[] tokens;

        FileReader file1 = new FileReader(customerFile);
        BufferedReader buffer1 = new BufferedReader(file1);

        //throw away first line
        line = buffer1.readLine();

        //continue with rest of file
        while((line = buffer1.readLine()) != null)
        {
            tokens = line.split(",");
            SSN = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            CNAME = tokens[1];
            GENDER = tokens[2];
            AGE = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
            PROFESSION = tokens[4];

            String insertString = "insert into customer values ( " + SSN + ", " + CNAME + "," +
                                    GENDER + ", " + AGE + ", " + PROFESSION +")";
            mySt.executeUpdate(insertString);
        }
```

I thought this was the right way to insert into a table. However, the issue I am having with is that the variables aren't being read in the right way.

Example rows:

```
3648993,Emily,male,63,Consulting
5022334,Barbara,male,26,Finance
```

With the example above, I would want to have a table with 2 rows and 5 columns but the code I put on top gave me an error when it reaches the name. I am not sure where the issue is.

Comment: Use PreparedStatement instead of string concatenations

Comment: How would that look like?

Comment: [Using prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: A complete example to insert to database using PrepareStatement.: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement

Comment: Why with Java? You can do this with a command line. No need to write any code at all.

Comment: @EJP just trying to learn how to do this with JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `insertString` with

```
  myConnect = getConnection();
  myConnect.setAutoCommit(false);
  File file = new File(fileName);
  fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  pstmt = myConnect.prepareStatement("insert into customer( " + SSN + ", " + CNAME + "," +
         GENDER + ", " + AGE + ", " + PROFESSION +") values (?,?,?,?,?)");
  pstmt.setString(1, SSN);
  pstmt.setString(2, AGE);
   ....
  pstmt.executeUpdate();
  myConnect.commit();
```

Source : [Insert text file into MySQL](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InserttextfileintoMySQL.htm)

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure that would fail - that's not how you generate a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Your connection object has 3 different names, and your prepared statement should have `?` placeholders instead of concatenating variables in the same way as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put quotes around string fields, so instead of:

```
String insertString = "insert into customer values ( " + SSN + ", " + CNAME + "," +
                                GENDER + ", " + AGE + ", " + PROFESSION +")";
```

do:

```
String insertString = "insert into customer values ( " + SSN + ", '" + CNAME + "','" +
                                GENDER + "', " + AGE + ", '" + PROFESSION +"')";
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally I do such things in two steps:

1) create a java class representing just one row of the textfile. This class is instantiated with a line from the txt-file and this single row is parsed and the fields are created, so I have for every single field a getter and a setter having the right fieldtype. within this class I'm able to perform tests and corrective actions if a field is wrong or even empty.

2) I create a Writer-class that reads the textfile line by line and writes every single line into the db, mostly starting with the second line, because the first line contains the header. I strictly use PreparedStatement and use batchwriting, at the end, when file looping is finished, write the batch to the DB with PreparedStatement.executeBatch() and then I close down all DB-objects.